# Select element by class name A when next to another element of class name B

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a load of `<div>`'s, all with the class name of '`a`'.

Occasionally, mixed inbetween these div's I have a  with the class name of '`b`' (these 'b' elements are basically category headers within my listing).

```
<div class='a'>item 1</div>
<div class='a'>item 2</div>
<div class='a'>item 3</div>

<div class='b'>category header</div>

<div class='a'>item 4</div>
<div class='a'>item 5</div>

<div class='b'>another category header</div>

<div class='a'>item 6</div>
<div class='a'>item 7</div>
```

Class '`a`' has a `border-bottom:1px dotted black;`

However, if one of these div's with class 'a' is immediately followed by a div of class 'b' (a category header), I don't want class 'a' to have the dotted bottom border, so I want to set it to `border:0;`

So, in the example above, I want to remove the dotted border-bottom style property from items 3 and 5 (as they are followed immediately by one of the category divs).

What css selector would accomplish this?

Comment: Can't really make sense of your structure; need to see your HTML. Or better, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo.

Comment: What you ask for is impossible - you could select the class 'b' that is the immediately-following sibling of a class 'a' div, but you can't select the other way around. Basically, you can never select "further down the DOM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realise that I couldn't select further down the DOM. My bad.

So, I've basically flipped my logic around a bit so 'a' has a border-TOP (instead of BOTTOM), unless it comes straight after a div with class 'b'. This has given me the desired result.

Comment: Argh, I was half way through a fiddle that was using `border-top` :-) so +1 for this

Comment: This is why I suggested a demo.

Answer (score 2):

How about switching things round and using `border-top` instead? The following will remove the *pseudo bottom* border from items 3 and 5 from your markup.

```
div:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
}

div {
    border-top:1px dotted black;
}

div:first-child, div.a + div.b {
    border:none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YyMMh/)

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with CSS, as far as I know.

You could do the following with jQuery, though

```
$('.b').prev('.a').css('border', 'none');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/XUhax/